# What is a raspberry?

Tags: meaning

Reading the paper yesterday I encountered this passage:-

> Desperately disappointed that the line-up of presenters for the BBC's
>   relaunch of Top Gear does not include a disabled person. Most of the
>   other boxes have been ticked - woman, black chap, foreigner, ginger,
>   elderly man. But no room for a *raspberry*.

I would like to know what a raspberry is, in this context. I imagine it is rhyming slang for something not very politically correct. Aside from the usual meanings of the word, Green's *Dictionary of Slang* has raspberry-lander as Australian slang for *Tasmanian*, but that probably isn't what it meant.

Comment: Quite interesting link, [DISABILITY RHYMING SLANG](http://messybeast.com/dragonqueen/rhymingslang.htm).

Comment: I just searched the online Green's Dictionary and the rhyming slang is definitely there.

Comment: @AmbroseChapel Online, is it? Splendid. I was looking in the dead tree version. Perhaps not closely enough.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Raspberry ripple*: cripple. Obviously no person of refined sensibility would use such a term, or even recognize it.

Comment: Worth adding that Raspberry Ripple was once (still?) a popular type of ice cream (vanilla marbled with raspberry-flavoured/coloured 'compot').

Comment: @BiscuitBoy, Urban Dictionary, like other dictionaries, records what people say (or write) it doesn't create or rule.

Comment: @ColinFine: Urban dictionary is not a dictionary; it is a playground. (That said, I am sure this piece of rhyming slang is in dictionaries somewhere).

Comment: @ColinFine - Most words in UD are. However some words like this one seem made up and unnatural.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I can assure you that this piece of offensive rhyming slang has been in fairly common usage in the South East of the UK for many years.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy this is [Cockney rhyming slang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyming_slang), which predates UrbanDictionary - and the internet - by quite a margin.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy it's the opposite here, UD is full of nonsense, but there are occasions when what it contains reflects more than the angry sexual frustration of its contributors. "Raspberry ripple" has had this pejorative meaning since [at least 1986](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091826/). Also the pattern is very much in keeping with rhyming slang patterns.

Comment: @MontyHarder Which has been replaced by "challenged". Which will soon be replaced by "special".

Comment: @MrLister Nope, you can't say "special ed" or "mentally challenged" anymore. Those followed "retarded", which is of course offensive too. I believe "special needs" is still allowed.

Comment: In addition, but not in this context, a raspberry is known in the US as a Bronx cheer.